# Why would someone connect a ground wire to neutral?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Removed a light switch and saw that the ground for the switch was tied into the neutral line.

Why would someone do this? Shouldn't the ground be tapped into the metal electrical box?

EDIT: Added 1 more image that shows a bit more. The ground from the romex is connected to the two white wires that's coming into the box.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Usually a bad hack(neutral broken) or just bad wiring by an idiot.

Comment: Can you give us a picture that’s not so close-in? What’s actually hooked up to what? We can’t see where that bare wire actually goes. There’s a difference between wire color and wire function.

Comment: If the box isn't grounded, going to the box makes no sense. If there is no ground available, it's arguably safer to tie the switch ground (and by extension the metal box) to neutral than leave it floating, because hot/live shorting to the case would trip the breaker instead of leaving the metal (including faceplate screws) charged.

Comment: The angle of this picture makes it look like that bare wire goes from one wire nut to the other. Please show us a different angle!

Comment: The angle, people want to see the cables from a different angle so that they can see which wires are going where. Not just uncropping.

Comment: Something _very_ bizarre is happening here. It appears that every single wire from the white switch on the left is going into one wire nut, as is a bare wire (acting as a neutral jumper from the white bundle of neutrals), as is one of the wires from the switch on the right. Is that _really_ what's going on, or is that just the angle of the picture deceiving us again?

Comment: Also, it appears that there are 3 wires (2 black and a red) entering the box as single wires, not in Romex/NM-B/cable. That implies that you have conduit in the walls (which is, generally, a good thing), but is a very important thing to know. Edit in good pics, showing all the wires in the box, where they come from and where they go to, and I'm sure this will be reopened and you'll get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not be done. It is illegal.
The ground should be attached to the box if it is metal, and then to the ground screw on the switch.
The neutral should be capped, it is not required for a switch.

Without seeing the whole picture, it is hard to tell what they were doing.

There are numerous reasons they may have done it. (Such as a motion switch? Older wiring? How many switches? Are there other things run off that switch? Regardless, it is improper)

Courtesy of the residential/commercial electrian laying next to me.

Comment: While "this is illegal" is definitely correct, this barely covers sorting out this wiring disaster.

Comment: @FreeMan what else is wrong besides connecting ground to neutral?

Comment: Read my 2 comments on your original question, @eclipsis. Everything looks wrong here based on the pics you've provided. If you add a couple of different angles, that will help clarify things.