# Why would someone connect a ground wire to neutral wires?

Tags: electrical

Previously posted [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/282280/why-would-someone-connect-a-ground-wire-to-neutral/282287#282287) question, but adding more clarity here.

There are two switches in my bathroom: one for a light, and one for a ceiling exhaust fan. The exhaust fan is powered by the romex in the picture. Before I redid the wiring (last picture), the ground from the romex was tied into the two white wires coming in from the top of the box.

When I redid the wiring, I joined the two white wires, and will be wiring the romex's ground line to the electrical box. I'm wondering if this is the correct methods, and if the original install was incorrect?

[image]

[image]

Comment: These pictures are better, but there is still no enough clarity. Organize the wires so that they are easy to follow in the picture. At the very least, you should have connector so that the NM is not rubbing against the metal edge of the box. Once it's clear where each wire is going, people can suggest solutions.

Comment: Aside from needing to be properly secured, that NM cable may just be completely illegal to use at all if you’re in certain jurisdictions (NYC, Chicago).